# Raspberry Pi 3 Not Upgrading

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, update, password

I am a new Raspberry Pi user. I bought a Pi 3 recently. I installed rasbian on it by using NOOBS abd SD Card Formatter. 
After completing the installation i set a root password by using -- sudo passwd
After getting a successesful message i tried to update the OS by using -- sudo apt-get update(it started updating without asking for user password which does't happens on ubuntu systems). Then i tried to upgrade OS by using command -- sudo apt-get upgarde

After this command i clicked yes when asked by the terminal. After starting the upgrade process i got error message which says --
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/chksshpwd/'
dpkg: error processing package lib-chksshpwd:armhf (--configure)
libpam-chksshpwd:armhf

Attaching the image of error which i got
[image: Complete error messege ....]

Comment: Have you tried removing that directory that the error message is complaining about?

Comment: @ElefantPhace No sir i have not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked me ... Type this to terminal.

```
cd /var/lib  
sudo rm -fr chksshpwd  
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I had the same problem. This indeed will solve the problem. It is exatcly what I did. One thing extra is you can use: cd /var/lib/chkpassword and then ls to check if the map is empty. Mine was so I removed it and ran sudo apt-get upgrade again!

Comment: I tried this but the system just appears to lock and not to resolve the problem.